# Javascript JSON search any match

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have some JSON:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [{
      "category": "reference",
      "author": "Nigel Rees",
      "title": "Sayings of the Century",
      "price": 8.95
    }, {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
      "title": "Sword of Honour",
      "price": 12.99
    }, {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "Herman Melville",
      "title": "Moby Dick",
      "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
      "price": 8.99
    }, {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
      "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
      "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
      "price": 22.99
    }],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

I want to do a search, and the result should return the node that contains the search text. For example, searching for `ref` should return:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [{
      "category": "reference"
    }]
  }
}
```

since that's the path that contains the string `ref`.

Should I do a recursive search and build the path?

Comment: I don't know anything about it, but [jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) might do it.

Comment: What happens if both the title and the category match?  Or if multiple books do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that builds this out of a number of reusable functions.

```js
//----------------------------------------
// utility functions
//----------------------------------------

// altered from Ramda's version
const assocPath = ([root = undefined, ...path],  val, obj,
  newVal = path.length 
    ? assocPath(path, val, (obj && root in obj) ? obj[root] : Number.isInteger(path[0]) ? [] : {})
    : val
) => root === undefined
  ? val
  : (Number.isInteger(root) && Array.isArray(obj)) 
    ? [...obj.slice(0, root), newVal, ...obj.slice(root + 1)]
    : {...obj, [root]: newVal}

const path = (path, obj) => path.reduce((o, p) => o[p], obj)


//----------------------------------------
// Helper functions
//----------------------------------------

const matchSubstring = (str) => (s) =>
  typeof s == 'string' 
  && (s) .toLowerCase() .includes (str .toLowerCase()) 



//----------------------------------------
// main code
//----------------------------------------

const findPaths = (pred) => (obj, curr = [], found = []) =>
  Array .isArray (obj)
    ? obj .reduce (
      (f, v, i) => findPaths (pred) (v, curr.concat(i), f),
      found
    )
    : Object (obj) === obj 
      ? Object .entries (obj) .reduce (
          (f, [k, v]) => findPaths (pred) (v, curr.concat(k), f),
          found
        )
      : pred (obj)
        ? found .concat ([curr])
        : found

const hydrate = (paths) => (source) => 
  paths .reduce(
    (o, p) => assocPath (p, path (p, source), o),
    {}
  )

const searchObj = (pred) => (obj) => 
  hydrate ( findPaths (pred) (obj) ) (obj)


const findSubstringInObj = (str) => (obj) =>
  searchObj (matchSubstring(str)) (obj)

//----------------------------------------
// Test case
//----------------------------------------

const data = {store: {book: [{category: "reference", author: "Nigel Rees", title: "Sayings of the Century", price: 8.95}, {category: "fiction", author: "Evelyn Waugh", title: "Sword of Honour", price: 12.99}, {category: "fiction", author: "Herman Melville", title: "Moby Dick", isbn: "0-553-21311-3", price: 8.99}, {category: "fiction", author: "J. R. R. Tolkien", title: "The Lord of the Rings", isbn: "0-395-19395-8", price: 22.99}], bicycle: {color: "red", price: 19.95}}};

console .log (
  findSubstringInObj ('re') (data)
)
```

We start with some utility functions.  [`assocPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath) and [`path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) are borrowed from [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/).  `path` gets the value of an object along a given path.  `assocPath` creates a new object similar to the old one with the new value applied at the path given.  These ideally would be in some central place in your code, or imported from an external library.

Next we have a single helper function, which tests whether one string is a substring of another, in a case-insensitive manner.  If you wanted a case-sensitive version, simply remove the calls to `toLowerCase()`.

All the remaining functions are useful on their own:

- `findPaths` returns the paths in an object whose values match the predicate supplied.

  ```js
  findPaths (matchSubstring ('re')) (data)  //=>
  // [
  //   ["store", "book", 0, "category"], 
  //   ["store", "book", 0, "author"], 
  //   ["store", "bicycle", "color"]
  // ]
  ```
- `hydrate` takes a list of paths and an object and creates the minimal object having those paths with values corresponding to those same paths on the original object.

  ```js
  const obj = {a: {b: 1, c: 2, d: {e: 3, f: 4}}, g: 5, h: {i: 6, j: 7}}
  hydrate([['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'f'], ['h', 'i']])(obj)
  //=> {a: {c: 2, d: {f: 4}}, h: {i: 6}}
  ```
- `searchObj` is getting close to your requirements, combining the previous two functions to hydrate a minimal object having all those nodes that match the predicate.

  ```js
  searchObj (n => Number.isFinite(n) && n > 10) (data)
  //=> {store: {book: [{price: 12.99}, {price: 22.99}], bicycle: {price: 19.95}}}
  ```
- finally, `findSubstringInObj` is your target function, combining `searchObj` with the helper `matchSubstring`

  ```js
  findSubstringInObj ('re') (data) // => {
  //   store: {
  //     book: [{category: "reference", author: "Nigel Rees"}], 
  //     bicycle: {color: "red"}
  //   }
  // }
  ```

I don't usually find quite so many useful functions along the way to solving a single issue.  This turned out to be a very nice problem to work on!

Answer (score 1):

[JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) is one option but you would need to know the field to search on.

For example `$..[?(@.price<10)]` would match any `price` path but still you need to provide `price` as part of the path etc.

Here is one recursive approach which flattens the object and records the actual paths of the `hits` with JS. It supports multiple matches as well.

The idea is to flatten the object tree (via recursion) and record a string path of every hit. Then once we have all the hits/paths we can just reconstruct the objects.

**Note**: The only lodash use here is at the end where I got lazy and did not want to re-create the [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) and [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set) functions (which set and get values based on a string path).

```js
let obj = { "store": { "book": [{ "category": "reference", "author": "Nigel Rees", "title": "Sayings of the Century", "price": 8.95 }, { "category": "fiction", "author": "Evelyn Waugh", "title": "Sword of Honour", "price": 12.99 }, { "category": "fiction", "author": "Herman Melville", "title": "Moby Dick", "isbn": "0-553-21311-3", "price": 8.99 }, { "category": "fiction", "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien", "title": "The Lord of the Rings", "isbn": "0-395-19395-8", "price": 22.99 }], "bicycle": { "color": "red", "price": 19.95 } } }

const search = (obj, text) => {
  let hits = []  // string paths of all hits
  const flatSearch = (obj, text='', hits=[], path=null) => 
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,value]) => {
      if(typeof value == 'object')
        flatSearch(value, text, hits, path ? `${path}.${key}` : key) 
      else {    
        if(value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
          hits.push(`${path}.${key}`)
      }
   })
  flatSearch(obj, text, hits)
  // You can just return the hits and it would give you an array of all the paths 
  // which matched or use lodash to quickly get the objects reconstructed
  return hits.map(hit => _.set({}, hit, _.get(obj, hit)))
}

console.log(search(obj, 'ref'))   // Single hit
console.log(search(obj, 'Rees'))  // Single hit
console.log(search(obj, '8.9'))   // Multiple hits
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Notice with the search for `8.9` how the `data` array has 2 `undefined`. This is since the match was on the 3rd array element. Since this was not shown in the question (what to do with matches on nth element etc) I left it like that since it is technically the correct behavior. The match was on the 3rd element and we do not care about the others. Now that can be of course changed to always be the 1st element etc.

The real `key` here is he `hits` array/result. That would give you the exact "map" of every hit found.

Comment: So why not use something like `new RegExp('"(\\w*?' + word + '\\w*?)"')` to find the matching word and then use JsonPath?

Answer (score 0):

Big fan of using libraries when possible here. But obviously depends on your requirements.

You could easily restrict the search path as well by adjusting the needle aka `**` of [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');
// const lodash = require('lodash');

const myData = { store: { book: [{ category: 'reference', author: 'Nigel Rees', title: 'Sayings of the Century', price: 8.95 }, { category: 'fiction', author: 'Evelyn Waugh', title: 'Sword of Honour', price: 12.99 }, { category: 'fiction', author: 'Herman Melville', title: 'Moby Dick', isbn: '0-553-21311-3', price: 8.99 }, { category: 'fiction', author: 'J. R. R. Tolkien', title: 'The Lord of the Rings', isbn: '0-395-19395-8', price: 22.99 }], bicycle: { color: 'red', price: 19.95 } } };

const find = (term, data) => objectScan(['**'], {
  reverse: false,
  abort: true,
  filterFn: ({ key, value, context }) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string' && value.includes(term)) {
      lodash.set(context, key, value);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data, {});

console.log(find('ref', myData));
// => { store: { book: [ { category: 'reference' } ] } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/lodash@4.17.20"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)